# Odd behaviour of "stack smashing detected"

Tags: c, arrays, gcc, stack

This is my code.

```
struct ar {
    char array[10];
}b;
void func()
{
    char array[10];
    scanf("%s",b.array);
    printf("%s\n", b.array);
    scanf("%s",array);
    printf("%s\n", array);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    func();
}
```

When i give string longer than size of array from command line for both array, I am facing **stack smashing detected** error for char array defined in main but array inside structure is not giving the error and printing the correct string.

What can be the reason?

Comment: One reason is that the struct is not on the stack.  It is located in the .bss section.

Comment: What is the program trying to do? Surely, if you could type a string long enough, even the array in the struct will give you something interesting to ponder.

Comment: Program is trying to know why array inside structure is not giving error similar to array declared in main.

Comment: "stack smashing detected" - so ask yourself, where does `b` reside, and how is it different than `array`? And does it bring comfort knowing you will likely  achieve your desired messaging if you move `b` into `func()` ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Basically what you have is undefined behavior when you do array out of bound access.
2. The global here is put into the .bss segment in the data segment and not on stack.
3. There is a possibility that everything might work as expected but that is a side-effect of UB , in another case you might see a crash.